# How to use android.support.transition

Tags: android, android-support-library

Google has just released android.support.transition that provides backport to its transition-framework. However I can not find class , any link to gradle or maven?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/transition/package-summary.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved it

build.gradle:

```
  compile 'com.android.support:transition:24.2.0'
```

Comment: But i can't find the TransitionInflater backport.Have you?

Comment: @Ajinkya Support library doesnt  support xml .

Unlike the platform version, this does not support declaration by XML resources.

Comment: I tried to use this, but it always results in `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.transition.Fade cannot be cast to android.transition.Transition` on API 21+, and no transition below that. Is there something special with the fragments? Like different method or something?

Comment: **NOTE** that this support transition API is for views only (for the time being, at least), thus you cannot use it on fragments. What a shame... ([Confirmed by Ian Lake in this Google+ answer.](https://plus.google.com/110757386741030050881/posts/gzzp2MZ1Wgn))

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy You're right.  I've just tried for "share-element" transition for fragment or activity, it doesnt work ever. But I have an example to use this supportLib for views, you'll get what you wanna maybe. https://github.com/XinyueZ/AndroidTransitionExample

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:transition:24.2.0' where I can add this android/app(build.gradle) or android(nulid.gradle)

Answer (score 2):

I was using react-native and solve this with: `npx jetify` on root folder.

Answer (score 0):

This transition support is really only for views-level not for fragments or activities.

https://github.com/XinyueZ/AndroidTransitionExample

Try this as sample of transition support library of Google.

More complex sample:
https://github.com/XinyueZ/image-transition-sample

Comment: If you are looking to support API 14+ use version 27.0.0 of the Support Library, which includes support for Support Library Transitions for fragments. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-0-0

Answer (score -2):

Open **SDK Manager** -> switch to **SDK Tools** tab, and update your **Android SDK platform-Tool** and **Android SDK Tools**.

Then **Sync** your project.